# Could Not Follow Redirect Path

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was debugging open graph for my new website and I have the following error:

**Could Not Follow Redirect Path**
and
**URL returned a bad HTTP response code.**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webcilento.com%2Fsite%2Feventi%2Ffiera-di-prova.html

This  error occurs only in calendar section (http://www.webcilento.com/site/eventi/fiera-di-prova.html)

I'm using Joomla 3.2.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What acute view! I haven't seen the double 'site' in the url!

Anyway the tag is added by a calendar plugin.
This is the code

```
// adding current url as url
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
              $protocol = "https://";
            } else {
              $protocol = "http://";
            }

            $fburl = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].KRequest::root().@route('option=com_ohanah&view=event&id='.$event->id.$itemid);
            $doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$fburl.'" />');
```

I'll try to debug that variables.

Comment: I was a script bug, code replaced with    $fburl = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].@route('option=com_ohanah&view=event&id='.$event->id.$itemid);

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error in the `og:url` open graph header which you have set.

The URL to your page is http://www.webcilento.com/site/eventi/fiera-di-prova.html but the open graph header says this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.webcilento.com/site/site/eventi/fiera-di-prova.html" />
```

There is an extra "site/" part in that URL - Facebook is picking this up, visiting that URL which then returns a 404 - hence the "bad HTTP response code" message. If you change that `<meta>` to the following, it should work:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.webcilento.com/site/eventi/fiera-di-prova.html" />
```

If these headers are added by a plugin or by Joomla itself, then perhaps something is misconfigured? If you provide more information about how you are adding the Open graph headers to the page then we can assist with that.

Answer (score 0):

After digging for 3 days came to the conclusion that name servers were configured incorrectly.

I am using Bigrock for the domain and GoDaddy for hosting, by mistake, I configured actual hosting provider host name in "Name Server 3" and "Name Server 4". But Facebook looks for the content in first server "bigrocks-1.com"(wrong server) server but does not find any hosting. Bigrock redirects request to next server "bigrocks-2.com", for which Facebook results into 'Using data from "URL" because there was an error following the redirect path.'.

Hope it may help you :)

[image]